# emacs: can I define an alias for use find-file in the minibuffer

Tags: emacs, ivy

If I have a file or directory I visit frequently, can I define an alias that will work in the minibuffer? I'm not looking for a bookmark.
I want something that will work in any situation that uses file path completion, like `find-file`, `copy-file`, or `org-insert-link`.
I use ivy, so when I insert an org link, after noting that the link type is `file`, I have minibuffer completions session for a file name.
I would want the alias to work there as well. In all of these use cases, I would probably just want the name to be expanded in the minibuffer, not actually visited.

For example, how do I replace this:

```
M-x copy-file RET ~/.emacs RET ~/config-git-repo/.emacs
```

with this:

```
M-x copy-file RET ~/.emacs RET myalias
```

to achieve the same thing. Also, note that if the minibuffer is prepopulated with an existing path, it needs to clear the prepopulated path.

Comment: (1) The question isn't very clear. An alias for what? For a particular file name? (2) Maybe check out [Abbrevs](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Abbrevs.html).

Comment: @Drew I have edited the question to be more clear. I don't think Abbrevs would work for this. I don't know if abbrevs works in the minibuffer and, even if it did, I'm pretty sure it would not clear any existing completion prompt for the file path.

Answer (score 0):

```lisp
(defun my/kill-best-file-name ()
  (interactive)
  (kill-new "bestfile.el"))

(global-set-key (kbd "C-c C-y") #'my/kill-best-file-name)
```

You can call this first and in the minibuffer do `C-y`.

Comment: Do you mean "...in the minibuffer do `C-c C-y`"? And what restricts this to the minibuffer? Isn't the key binding available globally? But what happens if a mode overrides the global key binding?

Comment: I don't think this would clear out any existing file path prompts from the minibuffer. I just edited to the question to make it more clear that that is a requirement. Thanks.

Comment: @NickD `C-c C-y` is just a random key that is probably available. If a mode overrides it then the key of the mode is used.